# Why isn't this systemd service resource limited when using CPUShares property?

Tags: systemd, cgroups, resources

Ok to get my hands dirty with cgroups and systemd, I wrote the most moronic C program I could think of (just a timer and a spinlocking while loop) and named it `idiot`, which I accompanied with the following `idiot.service` file in `/sys/fs/systemd/system/`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Idiot - pretty idiotic imo

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/idiot
User=bruno
CPUShares=100

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then I did `sudo systemctl start idiot.service; top | grep idiot`, which predictably told me `idiot` used 100% of CPU. Now, according to [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-Modifying_Control_Groups.html), we should be able to limit the resources of this service by the following:

```
sudo systemctl set-property idiot.service CPUShares=100
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart idiot.service
```

which I did, followed by `top`. But this still tells me that `idiot` is using 100% of CPU! What am I doing wrong?

Note: I also tried adding `CPUShares=100` to the unit file, to no avail

Comment: I think I have a vague idea - my service is probably not attached to the cpu controller... but I thought systemctl was supposed to handle this for me. Ugghh

Comment: CPUShares are relative to the CPUShares of other processes on the system - are there other processes on your system that could use the CPU at the time idiot is running?

Comment: Well, they want more than 0% at least, although nothing huge. But I thought systemctl was supposed to function as a strict resource limiter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `man systemd.resource.control`, `CPUShares=weight` would work as follows:

> The available CPU time is split up among all units within one slice relative to their CPU time share weight.

Since you've told us nothing about other members of the same slice, I presume there are no other members, thus it would be appropriate for service to use all the CPU.

If you want to play with CPU control, try `CPUQuota=20%`. This directive is documented like this:

> CPUQuota=20% ensures that the executed processes will never get more than 20% CPU time on one CPU.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea the unit of CPUShares was weight! Fantastic!

Comment: Haha, this actually worked perfectly but actually got my computer to freeze up to the point of not even responding to REISUB. Although RT_PREEMPT may be part of the reason here.